# Django static files won't refresh

Tags: python, css, django, static

For some reason the URLs for the static files in my django won't change.  I changed it from `static` to `staticfiles` to avoid conflict with my global static files.

My project setup is as follows

```
exampleproject/
    app1/
        static/
            css/
    app2/
        static/
            css/
    static/
        css/
    exampleproject/
        settings.py
    staticfiles/
        # static files collected here
        app1/static/css/
        app2/static/css/
    manage.py
```

My static settings in `settings.py` are

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

And it seems to work in my test environment.  But on deployment, it won't change the URLs on the page to `/staticfiles/` instead of `/static/`, even after clearing cache, restarting nginx/gunicorn and making sure it was up to date with git.

Comment: A few questions =) -- Do you mean the `static` templatetag is resolving to `/staticfiles/` in dev and `/static/` in prod? Have you also checked that `settings.py` doesn't have any rules that do different things in production (either environments, or the `local_settings.py` pattern)? Maybe SSH into your server and inspect the values of settings (`python manage.py shell`, `>>> from django.conf import settings`, `>>> settings.STATIC_URL`). Are you hosting staticfiles like this? : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production

Comment: `settings.py` doesn't have any additional rules.    And yea its resolving differently in prod.